# iPhone Losing Cookie

Tags: php, iphone, cookies

I'm writing a webapp in PHP that remembers if a user is logged in.  It sets a cookie and if that cookie is present and validated, the user doesn't need to login.

It works properly from a desktop, but on the iPhone, as soon as I close the tab and relaunch it, the cookie is gone.

Is there something I'm missing?  I can't see why cookies would be removed when tabs are closed.  It would defeat the purpose of many of them.

Comment: Ensure you've allowed your iPhone to allow cookies and not just from previously visited sites. Then make sure the expiry date on your cookie is at a sufficient time. If that doesn't work then post the code that creates your cookie so we can make sure it is being created correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured it out.  I set the cookie to only work over secure connections, but one of the URLs in my iPhone's history was not secure.